# How to convert generic type into String

Tags: java, string, generics

I am writing a function which uses generic parameters and converts them to their specific datatype adds them and returns the added value. I have done this for integer and double, but can't do the same for the string

I have tried using toString() function as well as String constructor but nothing seems to work!

```
public static <T extends Number> T add(T a, T b) {
        if (a instanceof Integer) {
            return (T) Integer.valueOf(a.intValue() + b.intValue());
        } else if (a instanceof Double) {
            return (T) Double.valueOf(b.doubleValue() + b.doubleValue());
        } else if (a instanceof String) {
            return  (T) String.valueOf(a.toString() + b.toString());
        }

    }
```

I expect that it should return generic type argument but it throws couple of compile time errors:

```
java: incompatible types: T cannot be converted to java.lang.String
```

and

```
ava: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to T
```

Comment: `public static <T extends Number> String add(T a, T b)`

Comment: How would `a instanceof String` be true if `T extends Number`?

Comment: Also: using `instanceof` inside a generic method like this misses the point of generics.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat if I use String as return type it will cause errors for two other cases ie integer and double!

Comment: @AndyTurner I am new to generics so I am trying to use it! I don't know how it misses the point of generics! Guess I have to learn more about it then!

Comment: The point of generics is to design methods which work **whatever** the actual type of T is. Not to write methods that only work if T is either an Integer or a Double, and fails for all the other Number types. What you're trying to do is impossible to do with generics.

Comment: @JBNizet but I was unable to add the values if i didn't use instanceof! Is there any war around which helps adding the generics with each other

Comment: No. As I said in my previous comment, what you're trying to do is impossible to do with generics.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks! Is there any other way without (generics)?

Comment: No. There isn't any.

Comment: Think of `ArrayList<T>`, the list does not need to know the type of object you are storing since it provides generic functionality for all types. Having an `ArrayList` that stores things differently based on the type of object, sort of defeats the purpose. You can tackle the problem you’re trying to solve using generics plus inheritance or IMO overloaded methods for each type might be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Generic type `T` is declared to extend `Number`. `String` does not extend `Number`. And this is the root of your problem. Either your incoming parameters `a` and `b` extend number and thus may not be of type `String` or your `T` generic type may not extend `Number`.

Another solution is to have your method as it is and not deal with `String` type there and add another method that receives 2 `String` params. However, note that adding 2 strings just concatenates them, so "2" + "4" will give you "24" which is probably not what you want/expect. If you expect Strings that represent numeric values you will need to write your own code to parse your `String` params to `Integer` or `Long` or other implementation of `Number` interface and then add them up